# Mac OS/X: finding latest version number available for each application installed

Tags: macos, swift

I have written a simple OS/X application (in Swift) that finds all applications installed on the current machine and then for each of these applications, displays its name and version number.

For example the output may be something like this:

```
App "/Applications/1Password.app"
    with 5.3 for versionOfApp

App "/Applications/Adobe Reader.app"
    with 11.0.10 for versionOfApp

App "/Applications/Amazon Music.app"
    with 3.2.0 for versionOfApp

...
```

What I want to do next is check each of these version numbers to see if a **newer** version is available to download, and then to display what that newer version number is.

For example if Adobe Reader has a new version "11.0.20" (but the version on the current machine is 11.0.10), I would like to show the following:

```
App "/Applications/Adobe Reader.app"
    with 11.0.10 for versionOfApp
    has new version 11.0.20
```

Does anyone have a good idea how to find the **latest** version number available for each of the applications?  For now I am happy for this to be restricted to just those applications available on the App Store.

Many thanks in advance.
Geoff

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693430/query-the-appstore

Comment: Every app in the Mac App Store has a preview page, like this one: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lugaru-hd/id413694169, from which you could easily scrape the current version number. I have no idea how to go from an app's name to its preview page on the Mac App Store, though.

Comment: 1)Get the first URL from: https://www.google.com/#q=site:https:%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com+yourAppName 2)Scrape URL for version number.